# Transpose and pivot data

Tags: python, json, bash, pivot, transpose

Please help me with the following issue.

I am trying to structure a dataset resulting from the extraction of a .json file using bash script.

```
Data:

1 host1 AAA   
   2 host2 BBB   
   3 host3 CCC   
   1 active 0   
   2 active 1   
   3 active 0   
   1 var3 123   
   2 var3 456   
   3 var3 789
```

The structured result would be as follows:

| host | Active | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 0 | 123 |
| BBB | 1 | 456 |
| CCC | 0 | 789 |

What tool do you recommend to perform this process, approximately 700k files need to be processed in one hour.

```
The sample of JSON:

{ "Report": [ {  "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.Active.1": "1",
   "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.Active.2": "0",  "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.Active.3": "1", 
   "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.Active.4": "0", "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.HName.1": "AAA",
   "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.HName.2": "BBB",  "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.HName.3": "CCC", 
   "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.HName.4": "DDDD",  "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.X_HW_Stats.BR.1":
   "123",  "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.X_HW_Stats.BR.2": "456", 
   "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.X_HW_Stats.BR.3": "789", 
   "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.X_HW_Stats.BR.4": "123", 
   "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.X_HW_Stats.BS.1": "456", 
   "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.X_HW_Stats.BS.2": "789",
   "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.X_HW_Stats.BS.3": "123", 
   "IGD.LD.1.H.H.*.X_HW_Stats.BS.4": "456", } ] }
```

Comment: My first inclination is to try to adjust whatever is pulling this data out of your JSON to get the desired format from the beginning. A sample JSON file (And what you're doing now) would be useful.

Comment: @ShawnThanks for your answer, 
I attach an example of the json file, it is important to know the amount of entries/records changes in number in the files.
I am currently using python -mjson.tool.